# SQL Query containing Timestamp Date comparison

Tags: java, sql

I have a table - event_log which has a field in Timestamp format. Some of the example entries are - '2016-01-28 12:37:48' , '2016-01-28 15:26:51'

Now I want to write a query that will select some rows between startTime and endTime. When I fire this Query in an SQL client

```
SELECT Time,Data
FROM event_log
WHERE Data IN ('player disconnected','Player connected to server')
    AND Player_Details_ID = '1'
    AND Time > '2016-01-28 11:46:49' AND Time < '2016-02-09 14:38:39'
ORDER BY Time;
```

it gives me the desired output. But when I write a similar query in Java it fails to give me the result.

```
sqlQuery = "Select e.Time,e.Data"
                + " from event_log e "
                + "where e.Data IN ('player disconnected','Player connected to server') "
                + "and e.Player_Details_ID = '1' and "
                + "e.TIME > " + "' + startSqlDate + '" + " and e.TIME < " + "' + endSqlDate + '"                    
                + " order by e.Time";
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think your `sqlQuery` contains extra `+ "e.Time >= " + "' + startSqlDate + '"` on 5th row (you miss `and` after this part). What is a type and value of `startSqlDate` and `endSqlDate`?

Comment: @mzy Sorry for the extra line, it was a  mistake. Also, both startSqlDate and endSqlDate are Java variables.

Comment: Tag dbms used! (Date/time is too often not ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: In your query, they are not variable names, they are literal strings. See how the syntax highlighter made them red instead of black? You have a problem in your quoting. I strongly suggest using a `PreparedStatement` instead of trying to build up a query from variables.

Comment: @RealSkeptic The first query is fired in an SQL client and the second one in the Java program.

Comment: I'm talking about the second query. Take a look at it: `"' + startSqlDate + '"` is a Java string literal containing an SQL string literal which is `+ startSqlDate +` **literally**.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Date time handling and literals are very different between the different DBMS products

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the values of any 'startSqlDate' and 'endSqlDate' variables you may have defined, the query submitted to the database will invariably be:

```
Select e.Time,e.Data from event_log e where e.Data IN ('player disconnected','Player connected to server') and e.Player_Details_ID = '1' and e.TIME > ' + startSqlDate + ' and e.TIME < ' + endSqlDate + ' order by e.Time
```

That is because your variables names are in the string. Change it to this:

```
"Select e.Time,e.Data" + " from event_log e " + "where e.Data IN ('player disconnected','Player connected to server') " + "and e.Player_Details_ID = '1' and " + "e.TIME > '" + startSqlDate + "' and e.TIME < '" + endSqlDate + "' order by e.Time"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 5th line should be:

```
+ "e.TIME > '" + startSqlDate + "' and e.TIME < '" + endSqlDate  + "'"
```

(Provided your variables are Strings in the right format.)

Your version doesn't use your variables at all, but compiles to a static String.

Answer (score 2):

```
"e.TIME > " + "' + startSqlDate + '" + " and e.TIME < " + "' + endSqlDate + '"
```

instead of this , try below

```
"e.TIME > '"+ startSqlDate + "' and e.TIME < '"+ endSqlDate + '"+ " order by e.Time";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need to write \' than '.
This should avoid some problems with strings.
Also as you can see you have variable names in string.

Something like that should work:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT e.Time,e.Data"
            + " FROM event_log e "
            + "WHERE e.Data IN (\'player disconnected\',\'Player connected to server\') "
            + "AND e.Player_Details_ID = \'1\' AND "
            + "e.TIME > " + "\'" + startSqlDate + "\'" + " AND e.TIME < " + "\'" + endSqlDate + "\'"                    
            + " ORDER BY e.Time";
```